Images as planes render out as white, glossy, poor quality or not at all
Im really new to this blender thing. I've been doing kinetic typography for this one song as a practice and to learn some of the functionality, but now im stuck. And have been for past 30hours.
The issue is, there are some images in the project, but those render out as poor quality, white blocks, super glossy etc. I for the life of me cant solve this.
What i have done so far is;

Check that object has lighting.
Check that it has assigned material.
Check that it is jpg. pjeg, or png (tried all three, with no difference).
Checked that it has texture
Checked that it has a camera ray.

They look fine in viewport, even in rendered preview - but once i hit render. Its just not coming out.
What am i missing? I will ad a link to the project if needed.
I am new to this, so i know it is something really basic that i am missing.

Can you show a screenshot of the shader node for one of these images that renders as poor quality? Can you also give an idea of what size the images are in pixels compared to the project render size? There is a possibility that the material of the image is set up with an emission shader that is too strong or that roughness is turned all the way down and they are acting as mirrors to the lighting.
